# how to add usergent to automatically generated soap client using WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I want to add UserAgent into the soap generated proxy client from remote soap service. How can I add custom UserAgent into generated client?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a soap header, you can refer to the demo below:

```
public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector

    {

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)

        {

            MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UserAgent", "http://my-namespace.com", "User1");

            reply.Headers.Add(header);

            string outputstr = $"reply:{reply}";

            Console.WriteLine(outputstr);

 

        }

 

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)

        {

            MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("MySoapHeader", "http://my-namespace.com", "asdas");

            request.Headers.Add(header);

            string outputText = $"request:{request}";

            Console.WriteLine(outputText);

            return null;

        }

    }
```

We can implement the IClientMessageInspector interface on the client and then add the soap header in BeforeSendRequest.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]

    public class CustContractBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior, IContractBehaviorAttribute

    {

        public Type TargetContract => typeof(ServiceReference1.ICalculator);

 

        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)

        {

            return;

        }

 

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)

        {

            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientMessageLogger());

        }

 

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)

        {

            dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new ServerMessageLogger());

        }

 

        public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)

        {

            return;

        }

    }
```

We need to add ClientMessageLogger to the service behavior.

[image]

Finally, we apply CustContractBehavior to the interface of the client proxy class.

[image]

In the SOAP header we can see the UserAgent we added.

If you want to add http headers, you can use OperationContextScope:

```
using ( new OperationContextScope( client.InnerChannel ) )
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    request.Headers["UserAgent "] = "UserAgent ";
 
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[
        HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = request;
 
    client.Test();
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you but easier way to call the remote soap service is to add the service reference to the Project as Web Reference instead of Service. Using Web Reference it is more straightforward to use UserAgent and Certificate. Thanks for the response by the way.